# Overflow-x : scroll works but items not aligned

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed div and inside of it an `x-scrollable` div which contains many items.
this is my code :

```
<div class="gallery-items" style="position: fixed">
    <div class="scrollable">
        <div class='gallery-items-item'>....</div>
        <div class='gallery-items-item'>....</div>
        <div class='gallery-items-item'>....</div>
        <div class='gallery-items-item'>....</div>
        <div class='gallery-items-item'>....</div>
        <div class='gallery-items-item'>....</div>
        <div class='gallery-items-item'>....</div>
    </div>
</div>

.gallery-items {
    position: fixed;
    .....
}

.scrollable {
    overflow-x: scroll; 
    overflow-y: hidden; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.gallery-items-item {
    height: 130px; 
    width: 150px; 
    cursor: pointer; 
    padding-left: 5px; 
    padding-right: 5px; 
    padding-top: 5px; 
    margin-right: 10px; 
    position: relative; 
    background-color: #4d4d4d; 
    display: inline-block;
}
```

but the items are not aligned on the same scrollable line.. (http://croisentoi.com/cafe/menu/ when clicking on a picture)

Is there something I miss ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top;` to `.gallery-items-item` to align them all to the top of `gallery-items`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using 
vertical-align:medium;

Hope it helps you..

Comment: Ya, you can try all the three options, top, bottom, and middle .. Any one should work fine for your design.